# Orthonormal basis in $L^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find an orthonormal basis in $L^2(-1,1)$ for $span\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

I know I must use Gram-Schmidt process in order to solve this problem.

The answer given for the first vector is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$ but I am not sure how that was solved? I will know how to do the rest if I knew how the first given span was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $L^2[-1,1]$, the norm of the function $1$ is $\sqrt 2$- so you need to "normalise" it dividing by its norm to get a norm one vector.

Now proceed- Gram-Schmidt is the right process.

Comment: Will the process go something like this:

Let $u_1=1$ then $v_1 = \frac{u_1}{||u_1||}\implies \frac{1}{[\int^1_{-1}(1)^2dx]^{\frac12}}$, then $v_2$ is solved by $v_2=u_2 - \frac{u_1 \dot\ u_2}{||u_2||}?$

Comment: @Robben: Exactly. This is how GS works :). Note that you need to divide $v_2$ by its norm too.

Comment: I think the thing that troubled me was the $L^2$ norm. Is the $L^2$ norm just $<f,g>=\int^a_bf(x)g(x)dx$ and $||f||=[\int^b_af(x)^2dx]^{\frac12}$?

Comment: @Robben: Yes- that's the formula... but if you are dealing with complex functions- you would need to use $\int_{a}^{b}f \overline g$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we must know the inner product defined on $L^2(-1,1)$ is 
$$<f,g>=\int_{-1}^1fgdx$$
So the first step of Gram-Schmidt process is unitization of function vector $1$. Then 
$$a_1=\frac{1}{||1||}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{<1,1>}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1dx}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$